# Accessing elements of series object without using index python, accessing values of correlation or other matrices

Tags: python, pandas, correlation, series

I have a dataframe df. I have taken its correlation and then found out the first four highly correlated values. These values I have named as relevant features. I wish to access the values of these relevant features (relevant features is series object)

```
correlation_matrix=df.corr()    #taking correlation of the df
cor_target=abs(correlation_matrix['median_house_value'])  #finding the correlation of all variables\
#against median housing value

#Selecting 4 of the most correlated features
relevant_features = cor_target.sort_values(ascending=False).head(4)
relevant_features
```

**Output:**

```
median_house_value    1.000000
median_income         0.688075
income_cat            0.553377
latitude              0.144160
Name: median_house_value, dtype: float64
:,4
```

I am getting above 4 features which have max correlation with median housing value as above. Now I want to access the values 1.000,0.688075, 0.553377 etc., basically the first column.

I tried below codes:

```
[IN] relevant_features[:,4]
[OUT]ValueError: Can only tuple-index with a MultiIndex

[IN] relevant_features.iloc[:,1]
[OUT]IndexingError: Too many indexers

[IN] relevant_features.loc[[0,1,2,3]]
[OUT]KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3], dtype='int64')] are in the [index]"

[IN] relevant_features[:,3]
[OUT]ValueError: Can only tuple-index with a MultiIndex
```

I read many questions and answers and articles but it is not helping me.

```
[IN]type(relevant_features)
[OUT]pandas.core.series.Series
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are really close, need:

```
relevant_features.iloc[:4].to_numpy()
```

Comment: This is giving me the indices names too. I just need the numeric values, no indices along with it

Comment: perfect. Thanks you. worked for me. I can accept answer after 10 min. Will accept then

Comment: Also how to access the first column? Names of attributes or indices, in this case `median_house_value`,  `median income`, `income_cat` etc? What if I need these in a list

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor - Do you think `median_house_value` ? then use `relevant_features['median_house_value']`